# Jenkins Pipeline Openshift Plugin

Tags: jenkins, openshift

How do you delete Openshift pods in that are Error State from a Jenkinsfile using the Openshift Jenkins Plugin? Can't seem to get the syntax correct.

I have a script that works outside of a Jenkinsfile, but ideally I would like to run this from a Jenkins Pipeline in an Openshift container.

for POD in $(oc get pods | grep Error | awk '{print $1}')
do
  oc delete pod $POD
done

Using the Openshift API, can this work in a Jenkinsfile?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Slave in hudson.model.Hudson.instance.slaves) {
  println('Name: ' + Slave.name);
  println('Label: ' + Slave.getLabelString());
  if (Slave.getComputer().isOffline() && Slave.getMode().toString() == 'NORMAL') {
     println('Deleting Node = > ' + Slave.name);
     Slave.getComputer().doDoDelete();
  }  
}
```